# How to properly use Javascript Async eachLimit

Tags: javascript, jquery, async.js

I'm having problems with using async.eachLimit. It works properly for the first 10 elements, but it doesn't continue past that; it simply ends. So, if there are 100 elements, it only does the first 10. This is clearly an issue of me misunderstanding callbacks. What is the proper way of using eachLimit with an external function that does not contain a callback? Or is it required for such a function to have one?

```
async.eachLimit(items, 10, function(item, callback) {
        outsideFunction(item.attrOne, item.attrTwo};
        //callback();  ---> leads to all running in parallel.
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
 );
```

Comment: What do you mean, "an external function that does not contain a callback"? Is it asynchronous at all? If yes, how do you know it's finished when it doesn't have a callback?

Answer (score 10):

Your issue here is you're using an async library for a function that isn't asynchronous (or isn't acting like it's asynchronous). What `async.eachLimit` does is go over each item in the array, only executing `limit` amount at a time, and waits for `callback()` to be called saying the current iteration is finished and can add another one to be executed.

In your code example, the callback (when uncommented) gets called immediately after it tries calling `outsideFunction` because the function call is non-blocking. It doesn't wait because async says "I've been told it's done, I'll go onto the next one" so all 100 will try and be executed at the same time. If `outsideFunction` is an asynchronous function, it *needs* a callback (or have it use promises) to say it has finished executing, and inside that callback you call the callback for `async.eachLimit` and then it will only do 10 at a time in the way you want. Here's an example:

```
async.eachLimit(items, 10, function(item, callback)
{
    outsideFunction(item.attrOne, item.attrTwo, function(someResult)
    {
        // Your outside function calls back saying it's finished ...
        callback(); // ... so we tell async we're done
    });
},
function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
});
```

If `outsideFunction` isn't your function, and the function is actually asynchronous, then it's either using promises or you need to find a library that writes asynchronous functions properly. If the function isn't asynchronous, then `async.eachLimit` won't work.

If it's your function, you should make it send back a callback to say it's done (or use promises).